# How can I count the depth in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, depth

I want to count the depth in a list of lists, so not the amount of elements but the maximum depth one list can have.

This is my function:

```
def max_level(lst):

print(max_level([1, [[[2, 3]]], [[3]]])))
```

should return 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
def max_level(lst):
    return isinstance(lst, list) and max(map(max_level, lst)) + 1

print(max_level([1, [[[2, 3]]], [[3]]]))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Explanation:

1. First check if object passed into the recursive function is of type `list`:

```
def max_level(lst):
    return isinstance(lst, list)
```

2. If so, proceed to add up the `True`s in the list:

```
and max(map(max_level, lst)) + 1
```

where the `max(map(max_level, lst))` returns the current amount of `True`s, and the `+ 1` is to add one more.

---

If there can be empty lists, you can replace `lst` with `lst or [0]`, where the `or` will tell python to use the list on the left side of it if its not empty, else use the `[0]`:

```
def max_level(lst):
    return isinstance(lst, list) and max(map(max_level, lst or [0])) + 1

print(max_level([1, [], [[]]]))
```

Output:

```
3
```

---

*Addressing @cdlane's comment, if you don't want to mix boolean values with integer values, you can add an `int()` wrapper to the `isinstance()` call:*

```
def max_level(lst):
    return int(isinstance(lst, list)) and max(map(max_level, lst or [0])) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to search through a list that is empty as well

Give this a try:

```
def max_level(thing):
    return 1 + (max(map(max_level, thing)) if thing else 0) if isinstance(thing, list) else 0
```

I've reworked @AnnZen's initial solution to add an extra check for empty lists and also to not mix booleans and integers.

Comment: Interesting. Though my second solution checks for empty lists, and adding an `int()` wrapper to the return statement will eliminate mixing booleans an integers :)

Comment: Your second solution doesn't *check* for empty lists, it *forces* the list to not be empty.  A valid approach but you need to describe it properly.  Your solutions sometimes return an integer, sometimes a boolean.  I wouldn't accept that from a student nor professional programmer.  Your code does arithmetic on booleans.  Not illegal in Python, but not very portable.  Should we be teaching this beginner to *program* or to *hack*?  Adding booleans has a place (e.g. "Code Golf") but this just doesn't seem like it.